# Should I expect to be invited to visit the grad schools I was admitted to?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school

I applied to grad schools this year. I haven’t heard from some of them but the one I was admitted to I was invited to come and visit. My understanding is that this is relatively common, but I would like a better sense of how common.

I want to visit the school I choose before I make a decision on where to go. My question is: should I expect to be invited eventually for a visit day for the schools I am admitted to? If not then I guess I should plan a trip myself.

To add to the context I will say that I believe I had a relatively strong application.

Answer (score 2):

In the US context, for most graduate programs in science or engineering fields, at relatively wealthy and prestigious institutions, it's quite normal for departments to pay travel expenses for prospective students to visit the department before making a final decision to accept an admission and assistantship offer.  In some departments, prospective students are invited to visit before admissions decisions are made, which is more like an interview.

For programs outside of science and engineering, or for programs at less wealthy and prestigious institutions, such visits are much less common.

I would ask the department about the status of your application, and if you've been admitted whether they are sponsoring recruitment visits.

Answer (score 1):

It can vary on funding and they don't always invite all accepts.

If you are interested in a school particularly, I would reach out to mention your interest.  Maybe it helps.

Also of course consider to do a visit on your own.